# python request.get() not working on my raspberry PI

Tags: python, httpwebrequest, httprequest, raspberry-pi

I have a strange problem with a python script.

```
import requests
argumente = {'NRBUS': 'LINIA_1', 'COORDONATE': '46.195323,21.306300'}
r=requests.get("http://www.roroid.ro/php/GPS_cloud/GPS_cloud.php",params=argumente)
print r.url
print r.text
```

On my PC is worknig without any problems but on my raspberry PI after some time I end up with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testt.py", line 4, in <module>
r=requests.get("http://www.roroid.ro/php/GPS_cloud/GPS_cloud.php",params=argumente)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 375, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.roroid.ro', port=80):    Max retries exceeded with url: /php/GPS_cloud/GPS_cloud.php?COORDONATE=46.195323%2C21.306300&NRBUS=LINIA_1 (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 110] Connection timed out)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How is your RPi connected to the internet? Do you normally have to go through a proxy?

Comment: Or, in other words, does `telnet www.roroid.ro 80` from the command line connect to the server at all or does that time out as well?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters raspberry is connected the same as the PC. Only diference is that to my raspberry I'm working trought SSH. On PC telent works, is able to connect to the site. On R-Pi is giving a timeout error.

Comment: From what I checked the only site that is not working from my raspberry is www.roroid.ro. I think is a issue with the webserver....

Comment: @roroid: That doesn't answer Martijn's question. Of course telnet works on the PC; does it work on the RPi, or not?

Comment: @abarnert: I already answer to that question. Telnet is giving a timeout error on raspberry. For a little period of time the script was working. Now it stooped working again.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your script. If Telnet cannot reach `www.roroid.ro` from your RPi, then your script won't be able to either. So something is wrong with your network setup, not with your program. This may be a question for SuperUser, or for some RPi-specific forum, but it's not a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It may be a problem with Raspbian. It seams that the errors are randomly. Some time the script works. Some time it doesn't.